# Converting a mesh surface discretized region to a solid region

Tags: computational-geometry

What is the best way to convert a mesh surface region into a solid region?

For example, we can obtain a mesh region of the surface of the left femur as follows.

```
lf=DiscretizeGraphics[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]["Graphics3D"]];
SolidRegionQ[lf]
(*False*)
Area[lf]
(*61 317.9*)
Volume[lf]
(*0*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
R = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[lf], MeshCells[lf, 2]];
Volume[R]
```

> 500052.

Comment: Or just directly `lf = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[..]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Doh. Thought I had tried it...